# ggplot geom_bar with errors not printing

Tags: ggplot2, geom-bar

Assigning means and se to a data frame and trying to construct geom_bar with error bars for 2 experimental treatments across two genders

```
library(ggplot2)


dff <- data.frame(group=c('NSI','NSI','SI','SI'),
                  gender = c('Female','Male','Female','Male'),
                  mean.Score =c(3.41,3.3,2.63,3.32),
                  se =c(1.92,2.03,1.73,2.21))
dff$group <- as.factor(dff$group)
dff$gender <- as.factor(dff$gender)

p <- ggplot(dff,aes(x= group,y=mean.Score,fill=gender))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F34444", "#0066CC"))+ 
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge',stat = 'identity',width=1.8)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean.Score-se, ymax=mean.Score+se),
                width=.2, 
                position=position_dodge(1.8))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 10,hjust = 0.9))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c('NSI','NSI','SI','SI'))+
  ggtitle("Performance by Treatment & Gender")
plot(p)
```

Two treatments: NSI and SI. Across two genders: Female and Male; data is corresponding mean performance and standard error of that performance. Assigning to a data frame and trying to plot a histogram with error bars of the data. Code executes fine in the window, but then nothing shows up in the Plot window. Thanks for any help for a relative newbie!
Mary

Comment: Code works fine for me. Are you sure you are running the last line. Maybe restart R/Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

probably go to tools > global options > pane layout, and make sure the plot is checked for the console window
[example of where to check in rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do7GE.png)

Comment: Hi Oloye, Thanks for the feedback and suggestion. The pane layout had Plot checked for the console window. I looked at your example and my setup was the same. Any other ideas? Thank you again! Mary